# Control alignment incorrect when publish to another server

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, controls

I have been working on a development server. And on my page, I have a number of controls like RadiobuttonList.

It looks all fine on my dev server, but when I publish onto another server, all the control's alignment are wrong. For example, for my **checkboxes**:

[image]

**Radiobuttonlist**:

[image]

And **Label+textbox** on the same cell in a table:

[image]

As you can see, the boxes/buttons are not aligned with the Texts.

In terms of the code, there is nothing special about it. e.g. for RadiobuttonList:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataValueField="Answer_NO" DataTextField="Answer_TEXT">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and similar for other controls.

I was initially using VS2012 Express, but since having these issues, I changed to VS2010 but the issue still persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since the answer is likely "you forget to copy one of my CSS files" you need to make sure you did not... All browsers have dev tools to check styles/list of loaded CSS (Pressing F12 have good chance to bringing the dev tools on).

Comment: thanks Alexei - I will have a look at the CSS file.

Comment: Hi Alexei - on my F12 screen - I found the culprit to be margin-bottom: 6px in the .input section. However, I just cant find this line at all in my whole VS project. Where did it come from?

Comment: well it may be cached by your browser try hitting ctrl+F5, you will notice the difference